# Passing managedobjectcontext while using SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm trying to find out the best way to pass my managedobjectcontext while using view controller containment.

In my delegate all that is instantiated during didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is the rootviewcontroller (SWRevealViewController), but none of its children. My menuController, which is the reveal controller's rear view controller, is loading a dynamic list of menu items using core data objects. Ultimately, I need to pass my MOC to that class.

I'm not sure what other info you guys would need. For those working with this third party code it should be pretty clear, but I can't find any resources on it dealing with MOC and core data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I understand that SWRevealViewController is a part of a third party library. How do you set up SWRevelViewController to use your menu controller class?

Comment: In my storyboard, my rootviewcontroller is of class SWRevealViewController. That controller has two segues defined, one to a front controller (sw_front) and one to a rear controller (sw_rear), which is controller that shows up when you slide the front view to show the side menu. The rear controller is of type MenuTableViewController (that I created). I want to pass my MOC to that object to load the menu dynamically from Core Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the SWRevealViewController a managed object context as an attribute and pass that on when you initiate other controllers.

Alternatively, you could give your app delegate (where you presumably set up the core data stack) the context and use a convenient macro.

```
#define MOC [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that this would require subclassing SWRevealViewController and using prepareForSegue:sender: to pass the context to child controllers.

Comment: Right. That seems to be inevitable / implied.